# He is wearing vs he wears

Tags: grammar

I was working on an English workbook.I spotted 2 sentences.
"Julia is wearing jeans and a T-shirt today"
"Meena has got a red coat on and she is carrying some flowers"
The questions here is this:Why the form"be + ing" is used instead of "verb"(Why not say wears jeans and carries flowers)
I am not a native English speaker.So I want to ask that how native speakers think about this.

Comment: Saying that "Meena has got a red coat on and is carrying some flowers" is a description of Meena at that particular time and place and that's sort of the context in which you'd use that structure.  Saying that "Meena wears jeans and carries flowers" implies that wearing jeans and carrying flowers is something that Meena does all the time.  The first sentence describes something that Meena *is doing*.  The second one describes something that Meena *does*, whether or not she's doing it right now.

Answer (score 1):

This question may be more appropriate for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

There is a difference in connotation between "is wearing" and "wears" (or "carries" or anything else in a similar construction). "Is wearing" usually means that the person is wearing that thing currently, whereas "wears" usually refers to a pattern of behavior. The sentence "Julia wears jeans" means that wearing jeans is something that Julia does (sometimes, all the time, etc.). That can be made more specific, as in "Julia wears jeans a lot," meaning that wearing jeans is something that Julia does often.